# Sort images after ROI (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, sorting, opencv, roi

I am near new to OpenCV world. I am working on a project which need (for now) to detect numbers in an image, select them and save.

This is the code I used:

```
# Importing modules

import cv2
import numpy as np


# Read the input image 
im = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test.png')

# Convert to grayscale and apply Gaussian filtering
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Threshold the image
ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find contours in the image
image, ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Bounding rectangle for a set of points
i = 0

#rects = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in ctrs]
#rects.sort()

for ctr in ctrs:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctrs[i])

    # Getting ROI
    roi = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    #cv2.imshow('roi',roi)
    #cv2.waitKey()

    i += 1

    cv2.imwrite('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\crop\\' + str(i) + '.jpg', roi)

#print(rects)    
print("OK - NO ERRORS")
```

It works a half. The problem is the output numbers (in image format, it need to be that way) aren't ordered by the original image (below).

[image: Original test image]

This is the output:

[image: wrong output]

What is wrong in the code ?

Also, you can note the `rects` variable. I used it to do some debug and I noted an interesting thing: if I sort it's content, in console the array of images order is right.

[image: sorted array]

Is there a way to sort the images in the original order ?

I also saw this [very similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646555/how-to-sort-an-array-of-rectangles-by-position) but I can't understand the solution.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no natural order given that the ROIs could be spread out in two dimensional space.

If you want to order them by x coordinate you could do:

```
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
```

and then loop over `sorted_ctrs` instead of `ctrs`.

Edit: More precisely:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read the input image
im = cv2.imread('JnUpW.png')

# Convert to grayscale and apply Gaussian filtering
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Threshold the image
ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find contours in the image
image, ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Sort the bounding boxes
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    # Get bounding box
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

    # Getting ROI
    roi = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # Write to disk
    cv2.imwrite(str(i) +  '.jpg', roi)

#print(rects)
print("OK - NO ERRORS")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I inserted your code right after the i=0 counter and put sorted_ctrs but the output is still the same. Images are not in good order.

Comment: Now, just to know, by what this process of sorting depends ? I mean, how it is done ? Who decide to take first the number 5 and not to start from the 1 ?

Comment: Well, if you read the doc: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#cv2.findContours, it seems they don't make any guarantee about the order at all. So I'd assume that it is an implementation detail and you should as a user assume it is random.